# How does this method get a node from a A* grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm making pathfinding for a platformer. I'm using A* in unity3d and followed [this](https://github.com/SebLague/Pathfinding/blob/master/Episode%2002%20-%20grid/Assets/Grid.cs) tutorial, although there is one method I don't understand.

```
public Node NodeFromWorldPoint(Vector3 worldPosition) {
        float percentX = (worldPosition.x + gridWorldSize.x/2) / gridWorldSize.x;
        float percentY = (worldPosition.z + gridWorldSize.y/2) / gridWorldSize.y;
        percentX = Mathf.Clamp01(percentX);
        percentY = Mathf.Clamp01(percentY);

        int x = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeX-1) * percentX);
        int y = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeY-1) * percentY);
        return grid[x,y];
    }
```

It seems to be getting a percent value of where the point is in the grid.
But I can't wrap my head around how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float percentX = (worldPosition.x + gridWorldSize.x/2) / gridWorldSize.x;`

First we calculate a percentage between 0% and 100% to determine how far to the right you are in your A* grid.  I'm assuming when `worldPosition` is equal to `(0, 0, 0)`, that means you're in the center of your pathfinder grid.  So `percentX` should be 0.5 (50%).

For position (0, 0, 0), the above line of code results in
`(0 + gridWorldSize.x/2) / gridWorldSize.x`, which equals 0.5.

As you move to the left, `worldPosition.x` becomes more negative, so `percentX` will decrease based on the above formula.
As you move to the right, `worldPosition.x` becomes more positive, so `percentX` will increase based on the above formula.

`percentX = Mathf.Clamp01(percentX);`

Clamp the percent in the range 0% to 100%

`int x = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeX-1) * percentX);`

Determine the A* node based on where in the grid you are.  For instance, if your grid has 10 nodes and you are 30% across your grid (`percentX` == 0.3), then you're in node 3.